# How to point a domain path to my App Engine application?(not subdomain)

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, subdomain

I have been googling a lot about this, but I can't find a specific answer to my question. I have a domain registered with a company different than Google Apps, and I would like to map all possible URLs from that domain to my App Engine app.

For instance, if a user writes **www.mydomain.com/helloworld** I want this request to be answered by **www.myappid.appspot.com/helloworld** (the URL in the address bar should remain www.mydomain.com/helloworld though). I don't care about subdomains, just the unpredictable words users might write after the .com part of the URL (e.g., **www.mydomain.com/randomphrase** mapping to **www.myappid.appspot.com/randomphrase**).

There must be a way to do it, because the Royal Wedding website was built on App Engine and they do exactly that (http://www.officialroyalwedding2011.org). They don't use subdomains for the main options of the website. For example: http://www.officialroyalwedding2011.org/tag/procession/page/1 is the URL for the procession.

Can I do this without a Google Apps domain? I did some research on CNAME records but it seems to work only for subdomains. Other questions in the website recommend reading this http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.html But again, it talks about subdomains and it doesn't answer this particular question. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your app handling URLs (i.e. `someapp.appspot.com/mypage`) and a custom domain name connected to the app (i.e. `www.yourdomain.com` for `someapp.appspot.com`), then the URLs should automatically be handled for your domain (i.e. requests to `www.yourdomain.com/mypage` will be received by the `someapp.appspot.com/mypage` handler).

**Example:** Assuming you have your custom domain name set up properly for your app (`www` CNAME record for `ghs.google.com`), requests to both `http://someapp.appspot.com/` and `http://www.yourdomain.com/` should be handled by the `IndexRequest` below.

```
class IndexRequest(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('Hello, world!')

app = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', IndexRequest),
], debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I think I understand now. I hadn't set up the CNAME, I didn't know you could point it to ghs.google.com. I'm going to have to wait 24 - 48 hours to see if it works. Thank you for helping a newbie :-)

Comment: And as Moishe mentioned, be sure that the domain is also registered through Google Apps.

Answer (score 3):

The first line of the documentation says,

> To serve your app on a custom domain, the domain must be set up with
>   Google Apps.

But there is a way to register a domain you already own with Google Apps. See the "If you're signing up an existing domain" section here: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=53926

Answer (score 1):

`www` is a valid subdomain of `mydomain.com`. Just configure your domain as described in the document you linked to, and specify `www` as the subdomain to map for your App Engine app.

Comment: A need that seems acknowledged is routing <domain>.com/nick to www.<domain>.com/nick and likewise even though you won't allow blank domains could we redirect everything and not only the root? There was a 3rd party service mentioned that does exactly this more I'd rather that google do it since I don't want another thing to b0rk. Thank you.

Comment: @Nicke You can now redirect naked domains in Google Apps.

Comment: Thank you Nick Johnson I'm looking for that setting and testing it for my naked domain is http://alltfunkar.com and the example for the path is http://koolbusiness.com/li Both these are google apps domains and I think I must've missed where to enable them in my domain setting. I emailed enom about it and hope for improvements to come.

Comment: Apps will route your naked domain to the 'www' prefixed one, not one arbitrary domain to another.